# Workplace custom integration authentication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I try to develop custom workplace widget for sharepoint. But, in documentation, I does not find how to authenticate users! Only with app access_token or impersonate_token, which is not secure...
Here's an endpoint for generate bearer access_token via sso? Or SAML assertion?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can communicate with Workplace via API only using access_token.

Comment: [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.